# Individually I can show you the way

Tags: riddle

> Disaster strengthens me
>   I bend what you see
>   Individually I can show you the way
>   I am alive night and day

What am I?

<sub>*First time poster here. Thought I would give my first riddle a shot, also any advice/pointers would be appreciated.*</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Not a bad first riddle! You can earn a badge by taking the [tour] and learning more about the site, and you can check out the [help] for more information on what we like to see in puzzles and their answers. Hope you stick around!

Comment: I can show you de wey (sorry)

Comment: I don't think a question should be closed merely because it attracted a lot of guesses. The accepted solution fits categorically better than the others, even though I was kind of hoping for an even tighter fit. (EDIT: I just noticed OP's comment about "NEWS". The fit is indeed tight as anything.) Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm confident that the answer is:

> The Media.

Disaster Strengthens me:

> Disaster and controversy bolster news presence.

I bend what you see:

> biased news sources obscure the truth

Individually I show you the way:

> one news source will have their own coherent story.

I'm alive night and day

> you have the morning and the evening news times (prime time)

Comment: Correct! Well done :)

Comment: @Awsum4sum  wait,  what? yay!  i solved my first puzzling problem.

Comment: Yep :) Although the "individually I show you the way" was more referring to each letter being a direction on the compass, N E W S. Your description there was just as good though

Answer (score 9):

> Faith

it is strengthed during disaster, alters the way we see the world, shows people how to live, and always alive in those who have it

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that you are:

> The North Star

Disaster strengthens me

> Blackouts would let you see the North Star better

I bend what you see

> Kind of a stretch, but it bends the light of stars close to it

Individually I can show you the way

> Finding it can tell you which direction is North and allow you to navigate

I am alive night and day

> The North Star is in the same position (roughly) both day and night

Comment: Nice answer but not what I had in mind

Comment: I thought for sure this answer (in a more generic sense) would have been correct. Especially considering a literal interpretation of the word "dis aster"

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Fear?

Disaster strengthens me

> Disasters make people scared

I bend what you see

> Mass hysteria / mass panic

Individually I can show you the way

> Fear is a mechanism for avoiding threats and danger

I am alive night and day

> (long stretch) Somewhere, someone is afraid on the Earth

Comment: Pretty neat answer...

Comment: Excellent answer! Not what I was looking for though I'm afraid. Also your last line made me laugh, seems a bit sinister

Comment: "Not what I'm looking for though I'm *afraid*" intended pun? Lol

Answer (score 4):

> The sun! Or more generally a star.

Disaster strengthens me

> Nuclear reactions, explosions, radiation!

I bend what you see

> General Relativity

Individually I can show you the way

> It illuminates our environment during the day...

I am alive night and day

> ...but it never goes away.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Perhaps you can explain your answers a little more elaborately? Not all of us may know about "General Realitivity"

Answer (score 3):

Is it..

> the mind

Disaster strengthens me

> When something disastrous is going on, your mind becomes more active to survive.

I bend what you see

> It's the mind that gives you the perception of your world. It can change the way you see things in life, both physical as psychological.

Individually I can show you the way

> You think with your mind and you are the only one who can access it, it's your mind that can show you the way. When you have to solve a question or you need to find a solution for something, you'll use your mind for it.

I am alive night and day

> Your mind is always alive, even when you sleep or dream.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Very nice answer, however, I do like to point out that at times the mind may go into panic mode, which in this case is the opposite of focus

Answer (score 2):

you are

> Ugandan knuckles

Disaster strengthens me

> Sonic hitting disaster frees up rings for you

I bend what you see

> You are so fast that perception of sight is distorted

Individually I can show you the way

> DO U KNO DA WAE

I am alive night and day

> I play sonic whenever i want. night or day.

Comment: If this is not the correct answer then the universe has depression.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Light?

Disaster strengthens me

> This is is a little bit of a stretch: perhaps instead of a physical light this could refer to the light of the soul? After a disaster, people attempt to help and care for others.

I bend what you see

> Vision occurs when light is bent or refracted.

Individually I can show you the way

> A flashlight comes to mind. Anything personal or handheld. You use light to guide you in the dark.

I am alive night and day

> The sun provides light during the day, we have light sources at night as well. (Including but not limited to moonlight)

Comment: The first line could refer to supernovae.

Comment: @F1Krazy Interesting.. I didn't even consider that..

Comment: Good thinking, but not what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

It can be..

> time. During a disaster one can know what bad time is. Disaster can be termed as as any misfortune happening to a person.
>
>  Time shows us various phase of life. As the time pass we see various things thought life.
>
>  If the time is right, and actions are correct it can show us the right path in life. We get to know what is right and what is wrong as the time passes and can thus select the right path in life.
>
>  No matter day or night , time doesn't stops or wait. It keeps on going or is there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> Your Brain or Heart

Disaster strengthens me

> Every time our heart or brain gets broken, we get stronger for the next one

I bend what you see

> Your brain and heart bends what we see

Individually I can show you the way

> Your heart or brain can show you the way to do things

I am alive night and day

> Your heart and brain never sleeps, it's alive night and day

Comment: Also during a disaster or trouble, we go into panic, which physically starts to accelerate heart rate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stretch but here we go

> Weather

Disaster strengthens me

> Often one weather catastrophe leads to another i.e earthquakes and tsunamis

I bend what you see

> Mirages

Individually I show you the way

> not sure yet about this one

I am alive night and day

> Weather never really stops.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

> Authority

Disaster strengthens me

> After a disaster, governments, organizations, and leaders take control, and institute more rules and regulations.

I bend what you see

> Authority has the power to censor, outlaw, or forbid things

Individually I can show you the way

> An individual authority, like a parent, mentor, or expert can make you into a better person and guide you.

I am alive night and day

> Authority (such as the rule of law and law enforcement) never sleeps

Comment: I don'tbknow too much about this one. Sometimes disasters can topple government into anarchy or complete riot.

Comment: Eh, I think it fits as well as any answer. And IMO is stronger for the individually line.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Prejudice or Discrimination

Disaster strengthens me

> when bad things happen, people tend to put blame on others allowing prejudice/discrimination to grow stronger.

I bend what you see

> prejudice/discrimination changes what you think of others in a bad way.

Individually I can show you the way

> when only an individual does so, it's prejudice/discrimination. But when everyone does so, it becomes social norm.

I am alive night and day

> prejudice/discrimination is there all day, everyday.

And all you need is

> someone to show you DA WEA. (too dark, had to lighten the mood)